# Hadoop Map-reduce job failed

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am currently using a hadoop 5 node cluster with 5 slaves 
Each datanode has a capacity of 8.7 TB. I am executing a map reduce job to execute 312 GB of data but got a error of Apllication failed after executing the program. I cant understand the error, firstly the map reduce job started , it got to 11% after that it started again from 1%.

1) Am i executing a bigger dataset that cant be executed in the cluster configuration ?

2) Do i need to configure out my map reduce drivers for running the job on the dataset, what would be possible configurations ?
Please refer the screenshot for details.

[image: Hadoop_map_reduce_error]

Comment: Read the errors at `url to track the job`, but yes, you do need to tune your YARN containers accordingly. http://crazyadmins.com/tune-hadoop-cluster-to-get-maximum-performance-part-2/

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 . Is there a way to know the maximum size of dataset on which i can run my map reduce job ? I have been executing my map reduce job on dataset upto 300 GB but whenever i try to execute a job on a dataset bigger than 300 GB it gives the same error. Is there any way to get the maximum size of dataset that my cluster can execute efficiently ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I do know I've ran Hive queries over PB worth of data before and it didn't use 9TB of memory. Granted, that's using Tez, not MapReduce