# How can i increase size of processing input data file in map-reduce job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, bigdata

Currently i am using a cluster with following configurations:
1 namenode and 5 datanodes. Each datanodes have 8.7TB of hardisk and 32GB ram. 
When i try to execute a map-reduce job above 300GB i get a error but when i try to execute a job with same code for dataset below 300GB its get executed without any problem. Looks like my cluster can not process above 300GB of data, is that the case? Can i process a map-reduce job for dataset above 300GB , what configurations do i need to change? Do i need to do changes in my Drivers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hadoop Map-reduce job failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48260146/hadoop-map-reduce-job-failed)

Comment: Please don't repost if no one has answered

Comment: Even if you aren't using Cloudera hadoop, this covers what you want https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cdh_ig_yarn_tuning.html